# Find a component using id in React testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to test React components and I see that there are two methods - findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass and findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag. Now, I have a div which has an id associated with it.

How would I find that specific div using the id? Does React have a findRenderedDOMComponentWithId method. I looked into the docs for React Test Utils and didn't find anything specific that way.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've abstracted this into a utility library, but you can use a combination of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` and `querySelector`

```
const elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
const myDiv = elem.querySelector('#myDivId');
```